# Using write() system call to output dec/hex value of char array bufffer

Tags: c, formatting

```c
int fd = open(argv[argc-1], O_RDONLY, 0);
 if (fd >=0) {
   char buff[4096]; //should be better sized based on stat
   ssize_t readBytes;
   int j;

   readBytes = read(fd, buff, 4096);

   char out[4096];
   for (j=0; buff[j] != '\0'; j++) {
     out[j] = buff[j];
     //printf("%d ", out[j]);
   }

   write(STDOUT_FILENO, out, j+1);

   close(fd);
}
 else {
   perror("File not opened.\n");
   exit(errno);
 }
```

This is code for a file dump program. The goal is to have a file and dump its contents to the command line both as ASCII chars and as hex/dec values. The current code is able to dump the ascii values, but not the hex/dec. We are allowed to use printf (as seen in the commented out section) but we can get extra credit if we don't use any high level (higher than system) functions. I have tried multiple ways to manipulate the char array in the loop, but it seems no matter how I try to add or cast the chars they come out as chars.

This isn't surprising since I know chars are, at least in C, technically integers. I am at a loss for how to print the hex/dec value of a char using write() and as have yet not seen any answers on stack that don't default to printf() or putchar()

Comment: Maybe I am not getting something but why can't you make a another larger buffer and fill it with the ASCII and hex values (putting the correct ASCII value for the needed hex symbol next to original ASCII value) and just print that buffer? Or is that against the rules?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I'm not sure what you mean. I have tried making an int* buff and write() still converts those to chars. The issue is getting write() to write the dec/hex and not make it a char, that's really where I'm struggling.

Comment: If you want the integer `i` which carries the value `42` be printed out as the "string" `"45"`, you need to write out two integers, one with the value `52` for the ASCII character `'4'` and one with the value `50` for ASCII character `'2'`. (See here for the ASCII <-> integer mapping: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html)

Comment: @alk My problem is the reverse. I have the "string" "ab" and would like to write out 61 and 62 (or 97 and 98) to the console.

Comment: `"AB"` is three integers. The 1st is `65`, the 2nd is `66`, 3rd is `0` (the C-"string"-0-terminator). For how to print integers read my previous comment again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a larger buffer, make the conversion from ASCII to hex/dec (as needed) in  that and print the new one. I hope this example illustrates the idea:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* pHexLookup = "0123456789abcdef";
    char pBuffer[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; // Assume buffer is the contents of the file you have already read in
    size_t nInputSize = sizeof(pBuffer); // You will set this according to how much your input read in
    char* pOutputBuffer = (char*)malloc(nInputSize * 3); // This should be sufficient for hex, since it takes max 2 symbols, for decimal you should multiply by 4
    for (size_t nByte = 0; nByte < nInputSize; ++nByte)
    {
        pOutputBuffer[3 * nByte] = pBuffer[nByte];
        pOutputBuffer[3 * nByte + 1] = pHexLookup[pBuffer[nByte] / 16];
        pOutputBuffer[3 * nByte + 2] = pHexLookup[pBuffer[nByte] % 16];
    }
    write(1 /*STDOUT_FILENO*/, pOutputBuffer, nInputSize * 3);
    free(pOutputBuffer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will print `a61b62c63`, the ASCII and hex values side by side.

This was done on Windows so don't try to copy it directly, I tried to stick to POSIX system calls. Bascially for hex you allocate a memory chunk 3 times larger than the original (or more if you need to pad the output with spaces) and put an ASCII symbol that corresponds to the hex value of the byte next to it. For decimal you will need more space since it the value can span to 3 characters. And then just write the new buffer. Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Not that it really matters (in this case), but this seems to be C++.

Comment: @alk if you are regarding a 0x prefix that isn't specified by the author:) Since I'm not expert at the differences, but where did I step outside C? Only with the #include <cstdlib> or with the array initialization too?  My purpouse was just to show the author the idea.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I was able to massage this in to the correct form for getting the hex codes I want. I'm going to mark this as correct, thank you.

Comment: I deleted my former comment about "no hex", as I simply was missing my glasses ... ;-). Yes it mainly was including `<cstdlib>`, which indicated C++. Besides this the casting of `malloc()` isn't necessary nor recommended in C. What is `io.h` for?

Comment: @alk Yeah well since I code mainly in C++ the `<cstdlib>` was in because of a habit. `io.h` seems to be where Windows keeps `write`.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
unsigned char val;
val = *out / 100 + 48;
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &val, 1);
val = (*out - *out / 100 * 100 ) / 10 + 48;
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &val, 1);
val = (*out - *out / 10 * 10) + 48;
```